# How i get preg_match_all(); from URL

Tags: php

**This is my URL:**

```
<a href="http://sbayjai.com/forum/index.php?topic=67433.0">test_curl</a>
```

I want to use `preg_match_all();` to get

```
http://sbayjai.com/forum/index.php?topic=67433.0
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
$text = '<a href="http://sbayjai.com/forum/index.php?topic=67433.0">test_curl</a>';
$regex = '<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>';

if(preg_match_all("/$regex/siU", $text, $matches)) {
  // urls
  var_dump($matches[2]);
  // link text
  var_dump($matches[3]);
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(48) "http://sbayjai.com/forum/index.php?topic=67433.0"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "test_curl"
}
```

The regex is taken from http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/ where you can find a very good explanation of all the details if you are interested in understanding how it works.

Comment: Thank you,I will try it.

Comment: You have to use the correct regex `/<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/` NOT `/\<a[^\?]+\?([^\"]+)\"\s*\>test_curl\<\/a\>/`

Comment: Sorry, I don't tell you So first I find "test_curl" is a topic and get url later.

Comment: Two things. 1) Use this expression to match `<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(test_curl)<\/a>`. Note that the url title is in parentheses! 2) Add pattern modifiers as in my code, that is `/.../siU`.